# SQL regular handling for page refresh

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a .NET web page, in the onLoad event there is a query trying to executing a long time SQL stored procedure (required 1 minute)
Assuming that user somehow refresh the webpage within this loading period.

How the SQL handle this unfinished query? 
Is it cancelled once the connection is terminated by client?
Or it will completely execute the entire stored procedure?

Comment: Can you test it? Run the sproc and kill the page. Test the output of the proc.

Comment: no, i just assuming it has long sql time, in fact the query isn't that long, thus UI cannot reflect the difference. And I want to know how SQL handle this case (or if it has handled at all), instead of how the UI react to it